# Typo3: All extensions gone/uninstalled after migration

Tags: typo3-7.6.x

It's happening again and again to me that migrating Typo3 from a server to my local dev fails because I am losing any extension install information. All extensions are uninstalled / inactive, even the Typo3 core extensions.

This is what I checked:

- DB has been copied and linked correctly in AdditionalConfiguration.php
- All files have been copied correctly typo3conf/ext/** is ok.
- typo3conf/PackageStates.php is ok and filled
- cache has been cleared by deleting all content from typo3temp/
- cache has been cleared in BE and Install Tool

Does anyone understand what could have happened here?

Answer (score 0):

I saw that I also had the installed extensions listed in LocalConfiguration.php

```
    'EXT' => [
    'extConf' => [
        'css_styled_content' => 'a:1:{s:32:"loadContentElementWizardTsConfig";s:1:"1";}',
    ....
```

After commenting this out (as far as I understand this information has been moved from LocalConfiguration.php to PackageStates.php) - and clearing the cache again - everything is working.